# Query on directory creation during build in yocto

Tags: yocto

When we run bitbake command to build an image, dirrerent directories will be created under tmp/work/. 
Say while building for Raspberry Pi, following are the directories created under "tmp/work" in build directory.

```
.
|-- all-poky-linux
|-- cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi
|-- raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi
`-- x86_64-linux
```

My understanding is what are the packages required in host to build will be under "x86_64-linux". Please let me know if this understanding is not correct.

Similarly what will be placed/grouped under "all-poky-linux" , "cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi" and "raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi" directories.

Comment: Builds are sorted by arch type, so for instance, if you have a recipe with only plain text config file, no compilation, it will probably go to all-poky-linux, then it will put native stuff in x86_64-linux, global target compiled stuff in cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi and machine specific stuff in raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi.

Comment: How to check whether a recipe is not having any compilation details. The "volatile-binds" and "tzdata" are under "tmp/work/all-poky-linux", the recipes are "[poky/meta/recipes-extended/tzdata](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-extended/tzdata?h=krogoth)" and "[poky/meta/recipes-core/volatile-binds](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/volatile-binds/volatile-binds.bb?h=krogoth)".

Comment: `inherit allarch`

Comment: If a recipe inherits "allarch", then it will not contain any compilation?

Comment: No, if you know that your recipe will not contain any arch specific stuff, then you can use allarch class for conveniance. Everytime you have a question, you can look at the [mega-manual](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#ref-classes-allarch), it contains a lot of answers :)